# Sidebar color not changing laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel

for some reason my sidebar color isn't changing, I have no idea why, it also even affect until my logout button which turn it into black in color. When I try to remove the code for the sidebar, the logout button color return back to normal. But I had already changed the color inside the css file already to another color but still doesn't work. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance

When I used the chrome developer tool to try change the color at there it work but when I refresh it, the color black remains there again, but when I try to change it inside the code the color black still remains there also:

```
ul li a{
    background:#ADD8E6;
```

Here is a screenshot: (all the way to the right is the logout button)
[image]

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                                        <title>SideBar Menu</title>
     <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="sidebar">

        <ul>
            <li><a href="{{route('home')}}">Home</a></li>        
            <li><a href="{{ url('/hire') }}">Waiting List</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="sidebar-btn">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </div>

    </div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#sidebar-btn').click(function(){
            $('#sidebar').toggleClass('visible');
        });
    });

    </script>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

style.css

```
body{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial;
      background-color: blue;
}

#sidebar{
    background:#ADD8E6;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    left:-200px;
    top:0px;
    transition:left 0.3s linear;
}

#sidebar.visible{
    left:0px;
    transition:left 0.3s linear;
}

ul{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

ul li{
    list-style:none;
}

ul li a{
    background:#ADD8E6;
    color:#ccc;
    border-bottom:1px solid #111;
    display:block;
    width:180px;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#sidebar-btn{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:20px;
    height:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin:20px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:-60px;
}

#sidebar-btn span{
    height:1px;
    background:#111;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    display:block;
}

#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(2){
    width:75%;
}

#sidebar-btn span:nth-child(3){
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to change color for `waiting list` in sidebar to black OR change color for `logout` in sidebar to white?

Comment: I want to change the logout sidebar to lightblue but for some reason the waiting list sidebar black is affecting the logout, I tried changing the sidebar color but nothing happen

Comment: So you want `logout` sidebar to be `lightblue` background color right?

Comment: yup, I tried doing something like this but doesn't work #navbar-header{
 background:#ADD8E6;
} @HirenGohel

Comment: Try to add css like: `nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right.dropdown-menu li { background:#ADD8E6; }"`

Comment: @HirenGohel nope it doesn't work, I have edited my question where I had attempt using the chrome developer tool, it work over there but when I try to change it in code nothing happen

Comment: Give `id` to left sidebar like: `<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" id="left-sidebar">` and then give css like: `#left-sidebar li ul { background:#ADD8E6; }`

Comment: Still nothing..

Comment: Last try: `#app-navbar-collapse { background:#ADD8E6; }` OR `#app-navbar-collapse ul { background:#ADD8E6; }`

Comment: Sorry it also doesn't work..

Comment: Try `.navbar-header #sidebar ul li { background:#ADD8E6; }` OR `.navbar-header{ background:#ADD8E6; } `

Comment: @HirenGohel could you help me check if the link that I put for my style.css correct? It still doesn't work..

Comment: I will try! Put it!

Comment: Put what? I mean this part  <link href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"> is it at the right place? Or am I suppose to put somewhere else? And also  all the other codes that you just now told me, do I put inside app.css instead of style.css?

Comment: It's right place, and all my code is in style.css

Comment: Ahh I see, hahaha really don't know why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

I Think Your CSS Has been Con fit , check That In  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWbvX.png)